# spawning multiple connections to port 80 when accessing from the ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, networking, ip

I have a rails app which is hosted in a shared server. last few days I have been experiencing a slowness in the site.

When I contacted the hosting support, they said,  It seems that each time when we access the domain it's spawning 20 connections to port 80

what are the possibilities of being such thing.

1. could it be a network setup issue
2. could it be a rails config isssue

anyhelp would  be appreciated, thanks

my site runs on

Rails 3.2.9
Passenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a programming error in the client, unless your server creates self-connections, in which case the server end needs attention.

Comment: Hi @EJP, yes finally it appears to be a server config issue and support staff was able to fix the issue after some time. thanks for the answer